# Implementing Waiting Module in FlashBuilder 4

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

**Background:** I am creating a multi-language web application using Flash-builder 4. The menus and text used are being populated through an external XML file. I have different XML files for different languages.

**Problem:** When the user changes the language the XML file takes some time to load. As a result the user sees a blank screen for some time and may get the impression that nothing is happening.

During this time I want to display a message informing the user that the file is being loaded. Something like this can be seen at http://gis.foundationcenter.org/worldmap/index.php.

A screen-shot is also uploaded here

[image]

Any help or sample code would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When user changes the language, compiler has started reading XML file then add waiting module and remove waiting module when last XML file has been read by the compiler.